# NPE when using setText on an EditText that use PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher?

Tags: android, android-edittext, formatting, textwatcher

### Background

I have an EditText that's intended for putting a phone number in it.
As such, I've used this function on it:

```
mPhoneNumberEditText.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

In some cases, I need to put there a phone number myself, so I use setText(...) on it (with a valid phone number of course, but it should even be possible with non-valid phone number too).

### The problem

I've found that on some Android devices (quite unpopular ones, which also have pre-Lollipop versions of Android), setting a text can cause the next exception. It's quite rare though:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at android.telephony.PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.reformat(PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java:158)
       at android.telephony.PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.java:135)
       at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:7626)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3859)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3708)
       at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:81)
       at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3683)
```

### What I've tried

I tried to get the code of PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher and see where it crashes, but for some reason the lines don't match those of the crash report.

I've also tried to get the code to make sure it's the one being used, but it has some special classes and functions that aren't available (for example "com.android.i18n.phonenumbers.AsYouTypeFormatter" and "com.android.i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneNumberUtil" ).

### The question

How do I deal with this exception? Why does it occur?

Is it possible some companies have changed the code, and this causes issues?